Laminas Framework - Enable query profiler to check SQLs executed
I have to enable the query profiler in the Laminas framework(Zend) so I can see which SQLs executed to return the response of the API.
I have gone through the Laminas document https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-db/adapter/ but didn't get anything.
Also, I tried the things mentioned in the blog https://procedurecheck.wordpress.com/2015/11/01/zend-framework-2-database-profiling/ but got an empty object of the profiler.
Is there any way to achieve this?
Help is much appreciated.
Thanks.
